# how to change image on a tkinter button - python 3.6

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I am in the process of trying to make a timer that includes a tkinter display with buttons to start/pause and reset the timer. The intention had been to have the start button show a "play" image when the timer was paused, and a "pause" image when the timer was running. The image is on the button itself, and while I can get the button to show the "play" image, I can't get it to change to the "pause" image.

This is my code:

```
# tkinter code start
control = Tk()
control.geometry('300x200')
control.title('Timer Control')

def on_start_press():
    if timer.is_paused():
        start_button.configure(image=start_img)
    else:
        start_button.configure(image=pause_img)

# tkinter controls 
start_img = PhotoImage(file='StartBtn.png')
pause_img = PhotoImage(file='PauseBtn.png')
reset_img = PhotoImage(file='ResetBtn.png')

start_button = Button(control, text='Start', image=start_img, compound=LEFT, command=on_start_press)
reset_button = Button(control, text='Reset', image=reset_img, compound=LEFT)
time_display = Label(control, text="60:00", font=('Consolas', 48))

# For this, we just need to add a timer and two buttons (Start/Pause, Reset)


time_display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
start_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
reset_button.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)


control.mainloop()
```

and it produces the following:
[image: window with controls]

But pressing the start button doesn't appear to do anything.
I've looked for help, here and elsewhere online, but everything I've found has been related to buttons changing images in other controls, never in the button itself. Any help would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
So, it would appear that my idiot self forgot to put the code in to change whether my timer was paused. This meant that my button *would* have changed, but didn't, because the timer kept reading as paused. So, for those of you out there whose code like this isn't doing what you think it is, double check your code's logic is doing what you think it is.

Comment: Try ```start_button.config(image=...)```

Comment: What difference is that to using `start_button.configure(...)`? I have tried it regardless, and it sadly still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you share the 3 images? And what is ```timer```

Comment: You can see two of the images in the picture I linked, as they're already on the buttons. `timer` is part of the timing code, which I had left out of this. However, while reducing the code to post it here, I forgot to add in the code to pause the timer. Doing that seems to have fixed my problem, so thank you for that